# How can I convert a list of strings (each entry is three numbers separated by spaces) to an array of numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, nested-lists

*Edited for clarity*
Let's say I have a list like this:
['1, 2, 3', '4, 5, 6', '7, 8, 9']
wherein each entry is *one* string of 3 numbers.

How would I get this list into an array (of floats), such that 1, 4, and 7 correspond to the first column; 2, 5, and 8 correspond to the second column; and 3, 6, 9 are in the last column?

I've searched through other questions, most of which aren't quite answering my particular question.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  There are many questions and tutorials that show you how to split and convert a line of numbers.  Most of your posted code is unrelated to your stated problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what that was until just now! It's not so much that the results differ from what I "expect"; I understand how I'm getting to this point, but I'm not sure of the next step. I have looked at other posts but haven't gotten those methods to work because they have a different issue than I do. I need to 1) be able to convert each number from a string to a float (I can't do that as-is, because each list entry has 3 numbers, separated by spaces) then 2) put them into a simple array with 3 columns.

Comment: Yes, I understand the general problems.  When you do your research and edit your posting, you're likely to get quick help.  Keep in mind the stated charter of Stack Overflow. Our main criterion is whether other people are likely to run into this issue, and whether the posting is clear enough that they will have an easy time to find an answer. Solving it for the original poster is sort of a side effect.

Comment: Thank you, Prune. I have simplified my question and after continuing to review other questions, I still can't *quite* find what I need...

Comment: You haven't asked a *particular* question yet; You've asked us to supply code -- or tantamount to supplying code -- for a problem that is a sequence of several well-documented steps.  You haven't posted any attempt yet, even a partial one.  Again, please supply your MRE (minimal, reproducible example).

Comment: I guess I'm too new/stupid for this forum. I don't even know where to begin and was just looking for the right "approach," like "try thinking of a for-loop that does XYZ."

Comment: "Right approach" is problem analysis, about two steps outside the range of Stack Overflow.  Break the problem into its constituent steps.  Solve one step at a time.  Using your numbering above: (1) How do you access each group of numbers?  How do you then access each number in the group?  (2) How do you put values into an array -- although I suspect that you need only a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D arrays to store the columns.

```
arr =  ['1, 2, 3', '4, 5, 6', '7, 8, 9']
new_arr = [[],[],[]]

for column in arr:
    column = column.split(", ")
    new_arr[0].append(float(column[0]))
    new_arr[1].append(float(column[1]))
    new_arr[2].append(float(column[2]))

print(new_arr)
#prints [[1.0, 4.0, 7.0], [2.0, 5.0, 8.0], [3.0, 6.0, 9.0]]
```